# How to smoothly move the background when toggle between multiple options in Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a navigation option. One of the option will always be active by default and will have a background color like this:

[image]

When I click on any other option, the background color should animate smoothly and move from previous option to the newly clicked option. I tried to search it but couldn't figure out the correct name of this effect. It should act like a switch but I want to build it for custom use with text written on the handlebar, which isn't possible in switch.

How do I achieve it using Vanilla JS.
Here is my JS fiddle link for what I have done: https://jsfiddle.net/1ex3y94g/1/

Code I use to toggle the background color:

```
function change(id1,id2) {
  document.getElementById(id2).style.background="lightgreen";
  document.getElementById(id1).style.background="red";
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="bar1" id="bar1" onclick="change('bar1','bar2')">
    Option1
  </div>
  <div class="bar2" id="bar2" onclick="change('bar2','bar1')">
    Option2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions).

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/72c5k4ub/19/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/72c5k4ub/19/

The two options are not animated at all. Create a "handle" div which translates from left to right depending on which side has been pressed. This handle just has the background color and no content. It lays behind the actual options (which do not have a background color). The handle does not impact layout (since it is display absolute). For the animation use transforms (for best performance. Not margin) with css animations (`transform: translateX(100%)`). `100%` referes to the width of this element.

Comment: Please put  your code in the answer.  You can still link to a fiddle, but you need to add it here, on the site as well.